# Reading an xml file using element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have one xml file.
Its looks like,

```
<root>
  <Group>    
    <ChapterNo>1</ChapterNo>    
    <ChapterName>A</ChapterName>    
    <Line>1</Line>    
    <Content>zfsdfsdf</Content>    
    <Synonyms>fdgd</Synonyms>    
    <Translation>assdfsdfsdf</Translation>    
  </Group>    
  <Group>    
    <ChapterNo>1</ChapterNo>    
    <ChapterName>A</ChapterName>    
    <Line>2</Line>    
    <Content>ertreter</Content>    
    <Synonyms>retreter</Synonyms>    
    <Translation>erterte</Translation>    
  </Group>    
  <Group>    
    <ChapterNo>2</ChapterNo>    
    <ChapterName>B</ChapterName>    
    <Line>1</Line>    
    <Content>sadsafs</Content>
    <Synonyms>sdfsdfsd</Synonyms>
    <Translation>sdfsdfsd</Translation>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <ChapterNo>2</ChapterNo>
    <ChapterName>B</ChapterName>
    <Line>2</Line>
    <Content>retete</Content>
    <Synonyms>retertret</Synonyms>
    <Translation>retertert</Translation>
  </Group>
</root>
```

I tried in this way.......

```
root = ElementTree.parse('data.xml').getroot()
ChapterNo = root.find('ChapterNo').text 
ChapterName = root.find('ChapterName').text 
GitaLine = root.find('Line').text 
Content = root.find('Content').text 
Synonyms = root.find('Synonyms').text 
Translation = root.find('Translation').text
```

But it shows an error

```
ChapterNo=root.find('ChapterNo').text 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
```

Now i want to get the all ChapterNo,ChapterName, etc are separately using element tree and I want to insert these dats into the database.... Any one can help me?

Rgds,

Nimmy

Comment: i tried.........                                                    root = ElementTree.parse('data.xml').getroot()
ChapterNo=root.find('ChapterNo').text
ChapterName=root.find('ChapterName').text
GitaLine=root.find('Line').text
Content=root.find('Content').text
Synonyms=root.find('Synonyms').text
Translation=root.find('Translation').text                           But is shows an error "ChapterNo=root.find('ChapterNo').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: Add that into your question, its' hard to read in a comment.

Comment: `root.find('GitaLine')` There is no text "GitaLine" in your example.

Answer (score 2):

To parse your simple two-level data structure and assemble a dict for each group, all you need to do is this:

```
>>> # what you did to get `root`
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> for group in root:
...     d = {}
...     for elem in group:
...         d[elem.tag] = elem.text
...     pp(d) # or whack it ito a database
...
{'ChapterName': 'A',
 'ChapterNo': '1',
 'Content': 'zfsdfsdf',
 'Line': '1',
 'Synonyms': 'fdgd',
 'Translation': 'assdfsdfsdf'}
{'ChapterName': 'A',
 'ChapterNo': '1',
 'Content': 'ertreter',
 'Line': '2',
 'Synonyms': 'retreter',
 'Translation': 'erterte'}
{'ChapterName': 'B',
 'ChapterNo': '2',
 'Content': 'sadsafs',
 'Line': '1',
 'Synonyms': 'sdfsdfsd',
 'Translation': 'sdfsdfsd'}
{'ChapterName': 'B',
 'ChapterNo': '2',
 'Content': 'retete',
 'Line': '2',
 'Synonyms': 'retertret',
 'Translation': 'retertert'}
>>>
```

Look, Ma, no xpath!

Answer (score 1):

`ChapterNo` is not a direct child of `root`, so `root.find('ChapterNo')` won't work. You'll need to use xpath syntax to find the data.

Also, there are multiple occurrences of ChapterNo, ChapterName, etc, so you should use `findall` and iterate through the results to get the text for each one.

```
chapter_nos = [e.text for e in root.findall('.//ChapterNo')]
```

and so on.

Comment: Note that on a large XML document, `/root/Group/ChapterNo` will be faster than `//ChapterNo`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example using [`sqlalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org) to define a object that will extract and store the data in a [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Unicode, Integer, Column, UnicodeText
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///chapters.sqlite', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class ChapterLine(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chapterlines'
    chapter_no = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chapter_name = Column(Unicode(200))
    line = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(UnicodeText)
    synonyms = Column(UnicodeText)
    translation = Column(UnicodeText)

    @classmethod
    def from_xmlgroup(cls, element):
        l = cls()
        l.chapter_no = int(element.find('ChapterNo').text)
        l.chapter_name = element.find('ChapterName').text
        l.line = int(element.find('Line').text)
        l.content = element.find('Content').text
        l.synonyms = element.find('Synonyms').text
        l.translation = element.find('Translation').text
        return l

Base.metadata.create_all() # creates the table
```

Here's how to use it:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

session = create_session(bind=engine, autocommit=False)
doc = etree.parse('myfile.xml').getroot()
for group in doc.findall('Group'):
    l = ChapterLine.from_xmlgroup(group)
    session.add(l)

session.commit()
```

I have tested this code in your xml data and it works fine, inserting everything into the database.